# ECharts - Make pie chart more responsive in A4 size pdf file creating through window.print()

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I would like to centralize the pie chart in box and make it more responsive when window is resized. Currently, its not in centered inside box, words cut-off and also not responsive in view.

ReportResult.jsx

```
<div className="col-md-6 m-t-10">
  <div className="report-tab-chart-sub">
    <h3 className="report-tab-chart-title">Operating Expenses</h3>
    <div className="operating-chart">
      <ReactEcharts className="echarts-margin"
        option={{
          series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            radius: ['50%', '70%'],
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
            selectedMode: 'single',
            data: [
              {
                value: chartManagefee,
                itemStyle: {color: '#1d7ff0'},
                label: {
                  formatter: [
                    '{title1|{c}%}',
                    '{title2|Property management fee}',
                    '{br|}'
                  ].join('\n'),
                  rich: {
                    title1: {
                      align: 'left',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    },
                    title2: {
                      color: '#999999',
                      align: 'left',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                value: chartWaterbill,
                itemStyle: {color: '#cd78f1'},
                label: {
                  formatter: [
                    '{title1|{c}%}',
                    '{title2|Water bill}',
                    '{br|}'
                  ].join('\n'),
                  rich: {
                    title1: {
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    },
                    title2: {
                      color: '#999999',
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                value: chartUtilities,
                itemStyle: {color: '#bde955'},
                label: {
                  formatter: [
                    '{title1|{c}%}',
                    '{title2|Utilities}',
                    '{br|}'
                  ].join('\n'),
                  rich: {
                    title1: {
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    },
                    title2: {
                      color: '#999999',
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                value: chartTaxes,
                itemStyle: {color: '#7be1b1'},
                label: {
                  formatter: [
                    '{title1|{c}%}',
                    '{title2|Taxes}',
                    '{br|}'
                  ].join('\n'),
                  rich: {
                    title1: {
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    },
                    title2: {
                      color: '#999999',
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                value: chartPestcontrol,
                itemStyle: {color: '#f0a808'},
                label: {
                  formatter: [
                    '{title1|{c}%}',
                    '{title2|Trash Removal/Pest Control/}',
                    '{title3|Landscaping}',
                    '{br|}'
                  ].join('\n'),
                  rich: {
                    title1: {
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    },
                    title2: {
                      color: '#999999',
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    },
                    title3: {
                      color: '#999999',
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                value: chartInsurance,
                itemStyle: {color: '#fc5532'},
                label: {
                  formatter: [
                    '{title1|{c}%}',
                    '{title2|Insurance}',
                    '{br|}'
                  ].join('\n'),
                  rich: {
                    title1: {
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    },
                    title2: {
                      color: '#999999',
                      align: 'right',
                      fontSize: '14'
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }]
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
@page { 
    size: A4;  
    /* margin: 10mm;  */
} 
@media print { 
    body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }
    #controlled-tab-example-tabpane-propertyinfo,
    #controlled-tab-example-tabpane-comps { display: block; }
    .header-set-bg-img, .footer, .no-print-button {display: none;}
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 460px !important;
    }
    .page-break {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
    img.static_map {
        display: block;
    }
    .googleMap{
        display: none;
    }
    .echarts-for-react{
        position: relative;
    }
    .echarts-for-react ,
    .echarts-for-react > div {
        width:450px!important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .echarts-for-react > div > canvas {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width:100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }

    @media(max-width:1400px){
        .echarts-for-react ,
        .echarts-for-react > div {
            height:200px!important;
        }
        .echarts-for-react > div > canvas{
            height:100%!important;
            /* width:auto!important; */
            left:10px!important;
        }
    }

    .line-chart {
        height: 300px !important;
        width: 400px !important;
    }

    .line-chart > div > canvas {
        width: 400px !important;
        height: 230px !important;
    }
}
.print-page-break {
    page-break-before: always;
}
.operating-chart > div canvas{
    width: auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Here, I have generated Pie chart using `echart/echarts-for-react` package. I had checked with props in `echart/echarts-for-react` inside `setOption` but didn't get any works for making a chart more responsive and centered.

Comment: Can you add some of your code samples in this question?

Comment: Added @PramodMali